# Create multiple hyperlinks in text column of library

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting

I am trying to create a column in a document library that contains multiple hyperlinks.

Unfortunately it's not possible to have a rich text column in a Document library (unless I'm missing something?). So I need to use plain text I guess?

It would be great if the hyperlink pulls from another column, however I can also just work with hrefs as static text as well, but I can't find anything about formatting a column to display multiple hyperlinks, for example some sort of split function based on a semicolon?

Appreciate your help.

Comment: @GaneshSanap FANTASTIC this is it!!! Thank you SO MUCH!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it using SharePoint online JSON formatting capabilities.

You have to use the hyperlinks and it's display text in plain multiple lines of text column in this format:

```
[Microsoft 365 & Power Platform Community]https://pnp.github.io/
[Sharing Is Caring]https://pnp.github.io/sharing-is-caring/
[M365 Platform & Power Platform Community Recognition Program]https://pnp.github.io/recognitionprogram/
```

Then use below column formatting JSON for your column:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "style": {
    "display": "flex",
    "align-items": "flex-start",
    "justify-content": "space-between",
    "padding": "4px 0"
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "div",
      "style": {
        "display": "=if(@currentField=='','none','flex')",
        "flex-direction": "column",
        "align-items": "flex-start"
      },
      "children": [
        {
          "elmType": "a",
          "forEach": "listItem in split(@currentField,'[')",
          "txtContent": "=substring([$listItem],0,indexOf([$listItem],']'))",
          "style": {
            "margin-bottom": "1px",
            "display": "=if([$listItem]=='','none','')",
            "padding": "2px 15px",
            "border-radius": "15px",
            "text-decoration": "none",
            "font-size": "14px"
          },
          "attributes": {
            "class": "ms-bgColor-themeLighter ms-bgColor-themeLight--hover ms-fontColor-neutralPrimaryAlt ms-fontColor-themePrimary--hover",
            "href": "=replaceAll(substring([$listItem],indexOf([$listItem],']')+1,indexOf([$listItem]+'^','^')),'\n','')",
            "target": "_blank"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "customRowAction": {
        "action": "editProps"
      },
      "attributes": {
        "iconName": "Edit",
        "class": "ms-fontSize-s ms-bgColor-themeLight ms-bgColor-neutralTertiary--hover"
      },
      "style": {
        "display": "inline-block",
        "cursor": "pointer",
        "margin": "0 5px",
        "padding": "4px",
        "border-radius": "100px"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**Output**:

[image]

**Source**: [Multiple hyperlinks in single field](https://github.com/pnp/List-Formatting/tree/master/column-samples/text-multiple-hyperlinks)

Remember to use the *internal name* of columns in JSON formatting wherever required. You can get the internal name of your columns by following this article: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)

---

Here's another JSON sample which might help you: [Multi-Choice Links](https://github.com/pnp/List-Formatting/tree/master/column-samples/multi-choice-links)

[image]